# Some one suggested me to use VIM for html editing. I am using windows7. Does it make sense to use it?

Tags: html, css, vim, dreamweaver, emmet

For fast coding or zen coding some suggested me to us VIM but I dont have a mac. I am using Windows7. Can/should I switch to VIM from dreamweaver?

Comment: Not sure whether this works on Windows. Open your command prompt and type vim, then the enter key. This is VIM. It's up to you to decide whether or not it's for you. But I doubt it is when you are using Dreamweaver now...

Comment: It has a version for windows but is it worth learning?

Comment: You'll need to read about Vim (or any other editor actually) and see if it's a good fit for *you*. Nobody can tell you that, as it's obvious from Jarrod's answer.

Comment: @lc2817 - Of course VIM is easier to install than Emacs on Windows. It's not easy to install an operating system on top of another operating system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vim**

**Vim** can be really powerful if you know how to use it. But it can take a lot of time to know how to use it. The concurrent of vim is **emacs** and I can say exactly the same sentence about it. I use vim everyday and I can't stand using Dreamweaver for example!

**Transition**

Switching from dreamweaver to vim might be too difficult, use **notepad++** intermediary. But Vim is usable on windows 7, no doubt.

Switch only to Vim when you feel confident using standard editor and not [wysiwyg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editors and if you really feel like you are ready to learn and struggle (from dreamweaver to vim is too painful in my opinion).

Comment: I have no problem in using notepad++ so it means its time to switch.

Comment: @Imran yes: start here http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim